# Stop a thread from an Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, java-threads

I have the next Thread in Android to receive data:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    try{
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(puerto);
        int contador=0;
        while(!end){
            try{
                ss.setSoTimeout(6000);
                Socket s=ss.accept();

                BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                stringData=input.readLine();
                output.flush();
                contador++;

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                output.close();
                s.close();
            }catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                end=true;
            }

        }
        ss.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When the code reaches the SocketTimeOutException, I want to stop the thread from the next activity:

```
buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dirIP=editTextDirIP.getText().toString();
        hebraRecibir.start();
        hebraEnviar.start();
    }
});
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Your thread already stops when reaching SocketTimeoutException... So what is your question ?

Comment: I am doing an app to send and receive data, so when I want to receive data, I wait 6 seconds listening. When the code reachs this 6 seconds and there isn't answers, I want that the thread stops, and inform that the server didn't receive anything.

Comment: So your problem is not about stopping the Thread (because you already do that) but about "How to send an info back from Thread to main ?". First edit your question to make it clear. Second there are many ways to do so, for example you can trigger a function (look for Listener, or Receiver). But I think the easiest way in your case, is to use BackgroundTask instead of custom Thread (and use onPostExecute to manage your case)